# I have 2 sumifs fomulas. I would like to use one vs the other based on if 3 criteria are met or not. If statement not working

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, sumifs

First post here.  Looking for some guidance as an excel novice.

I have a daily CSV report which I copy and paste to a "Data Dump" tab (dynamic).  A "Data Pull" tab pulls and populates from this daily data dump.

I want cells in the "Data Pull" tab to determine whether the relevant sumifs should be a positive(debit) or negative(credit) figure based on 4 different criteria.  (Date, master acct #, and sister acct #, Credit vs. Debit).  The unique identifier in this instance is whether the item is a "Credits" or "Debits".  If the item being pulled is a "Credit" then it should be a negative figure.

I've tried If(AND statements with multiple criteria.

Tried IF array statements with multiple criteria

Tried to incorporate isnumber(search) as well.

```
=IF(AND('Data Dump'!$B:$B='Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$A:$A='Data Pull'!$B6,'Data Dump'!$H:$H='Data Pull'!C6,'Data Dump'!$C:$C="Credits"),SUMIFS('Data Dump'!$F:$F,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$H:$H,'Data Pull'!C$5,'Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25)*-1,SUMIFS('Data Dump'!$F:$F,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$H:$H,'Data Pull'!C$5,'Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25))
```

Here is my current statement that is not working.  It is probably a bit redundant, but am not sure how to properly lay this data pull out.  Probably overthinking this ... but there is a lot of logic throughout.

Please reference excel file attached.

[Excel Dummy File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGaII2GMgZjndKvcZo7RNAv06kRSI9b8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For starters, you're referencing `'Data Pull'!C6` in one spot, but that's ACTUALLY the same cell you started your formula in.  I think you meant `'DataPull'!C$5` instead of `C6` (this is what is in your 'Dummy File' FWIW).  This likely started the 'Circular reference' error I saw.

Comment: Hi @gravity - you are absolutely correct.  Missed error on my part.  I did update the formula to reflect C5 opposed to C6.  The pull works, but still C25 on "Data Pull" is not reading as a negative figure as intended.  I've updated the attached file to reflect changes.

Comment: In `C25` try: `=SUMIFS('Data Dump'!$F:$F,'Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5)*IF(COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5,'Data Dump'!$C:$C,"Debits")>0,1,-1)` and drag to the right into your matrix.

Comment: Can the sister accounts show up more than once per day?

Comment: @JvdV - That's definitely an answer, as it works as intended.  You should post as a proper answer, and if possible, a breakdown of why you changed what you did.

Comment: @gravity, if it works for OP I will do so when I get behind a pc! :)

Comment: @Luck  Yes - sister account has potential to appear more than once in a given day.  Chances are < 1% of that happening though.

Comment: @JvdV  your formula worked!  Thank you so much!  I've been tied up on this for nearly 2 days.  Greatly appreciate the response!

Comment: @gravity done. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

So to break down my answer in the comment section:

Put the following formula in `C25`:

```
=SUMIFS('Data Dump'!$F:$F,'Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5)*IF(COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5,'Data Dump'!$C:$C,"Debits")>0,1,-1)
```

Drag down, up and right into your matrix.

---

Why does this work as intended? Break down in two parts:

1) The `SUMIFS` part is used to check for all criteria from OP and return the full sum of matched rows (even for the 1% chance of sister accounts)

```
=SUMIFS('Data Dump'!$F:$F,'Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5)
```

2) As the above always returns a positive value, we need to multiply it either with a `1` or `-1` in relation to `Debits` or `Credits`. Therefor we can use `COUNTIFS`, to check if, with those same criteria there are any `Debits` values.

```
IF(COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!$A:$A,'Data Pull'!$B25,'Data Dump'!$B:$B,'Data Pull'!$A$1,'Data Dump'!$G:$G,'Data Pull'!C$5,'Data Dump'!$C:$C,"Debits")>0,1,-1)
```

---

> **Note:** This will just test if there is any `Debits` and will multiply the full sum at once. So sister accounts with difference in
>   `Debits` or `Credits` won't work.